# Getting Manifest Merger Issue While adding Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, android-manifest

I am trying to create an with facebook login.But when I added the dependency in the gradle it gave me a error like below:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38
    is also present at [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override.
```

So many of the SO answers suggest adding `tools:replace="android:value"` (SO questions were having different value problems though like the theme, icon etc).So I added that in my application tag. Now I am getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

I am using the latest android studio which has some version problems with many other dependencies I have seen.Though when I added facebook android SDK 4.0.0 it did not require to add `tools:replace="android:value"` and gradle built fine but old SDK does not have CustomTabActivity feature which opens Google Chrome. What should I do?

Below my current manifest and build.gradle(app level) file:

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mranuran.buyhatkeassignmentone"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.mranuran.buyhatkeassignmentone">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:replace="android:value"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `multiDexEnabled true` in build.gradle file like this:

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.user.googlemapdemonew"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    //Add this
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

and this dependency;

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it!

change

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

to

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)') {
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7'
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
}
```

instead of

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```